# SQLite find words with two "a" letters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to filter out words that have two letter "a"'s in them.

I've tried using LIKE, but can't figure out how to filter words with two "a"'s (they don't have to be consecutive).

`SELECT Sanat.sana FROM Sanat WHERE Sanat.sana LIKE '%a%';`

Comment: `LIKE '%a%a%';`

Comment: That also returns words with more than two a's

Comment: Did you mean exactly 2 a's?

Comment: Yes, I did  mean that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For exactly 2 a's you could do:

```
SELECT Sanat.sana FROM Sanat WHERE LENGTH(REPLACE(Sanat.sana, 'a', '')) = LENGTH(Sanat.sana) - 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

"LIKE '%a%a%'" would also show words with more than 2 a's.

You could instead use something like this:

SELECT sana FROM Sanat WHERE sana LIKE '%a%a%' AND sana NOT LIKE '%a%a%a%';

Answer (score 0):

You would use `like`:

```
WHERE Sanat.sana LIKE '%a%a%';
```

Note:  This will generally also match upper-case `'a'`s.